# Can't use method return value in write context; session data

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I know lots of people have asked this question but the answers I looked at didn't help.

I have data set in the session that I need to send to the view but obviously only if the data is there.

This is MY_Controller file in the core folder of codeigniter. (I need this code ran throughout the site)

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct () {
    parent::__construct();
    if (!$this->session->userdata('loggedIn')) {
        $this->data('loggedIn') = $this->session->userdata('loggedIn');
        $this->data('masterEmail') = $this->session->userdata('email');
        }

   }

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use same code in that view file itself. If you want in more than one view file, then you can write the below code in template library file.

```
if (!$this->session->userdata('loggedIn')) {
    $loggedIn = $this->session->userdata('loggedIn');
    $masterEmail = $this->session->userdata('email');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Haven't been coding in a while. Felt like it was gonna be something really dumb like that.